# Dynamically generate a <li>?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<span id="n-email" class="email-btn"><a href="#."></a></span>
```

On clicking this, a list item with a text field shows

```
<li id="new" class="select">
    <a>
        <input type="text" id="emails" class="add-email" value="Untitled" onfocus="if(this.value=='Untitled'){this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value=='')  {this.value='Untitled'}"/>
    </a>
</li>
```

Suppose I filled something in this input field and press enter.
On pressing enter I want to fire a event which would

1. Remove the `<li>` containing the input field.
2. Insert new `<li>` in its place, like

   ```
   <li>
       <a href="#.">
           //here comes the value what we entered in the input field of above li//
       </a>
   </li>
   ```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? At least give it a go on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Until someone gets more than say 500 rep, there should be a section to fill up in the question form that includes google search attempts (minimum 3) and a jsfiddle link. Aaaargghhh, enough of this spoon-feeding.

Comment: somebody don't even say please !

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.. but you have to modify it to your example values:

```
$('li').each(function() {
    var input = $(this).find('input');
    $(this).append(input.val());
    input.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to hide the `#new` row, then you need to use `keypress` event to catch the enter key, finally use the `append()` method to insert a new element.

Here is a example based on your script

```
$(".email-btn").click(function() {
    $("#new").show();
});

$("#emails").keypress(function(e)
{
    value = $(this).val();
    code= (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 13) {
        $("#new").remove();
        $("#mylist").append("<li><a>"+value+"</a></li>");
    }

});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/Gk7p6/3/)